# Почему class_exists показывает что класс не существует

Tags: php

```
public static function dipacher($url)
{
       if (self::compareRoute($url)){
       $controller = self::$route['controller'];

       echo $controller; //HomeController

           if (class_exists($controller)){
               echo "exists";
           }else{

               echo "does not exist";
           }

       }else {
        //redirct

    }
}
```

`use Controller\HomeController` имеется, автозагрузка классов через composer. Экземпляр класса создается если написать `$obj = new HomeController`

Comment: Дополнение. use Controller\HomeController имеется, автозагрузка классов через composer. Экземпляр класса создается если написать $obj = new HomeController

Comment: Так как ваш класс располагается в отдельном файле, то он НЕ БУДЕТ присутствовать, пока этот файл не загружен. Т.е. после `$obj = new HomeController()`, `class_exists` покажет, что он присутствует в контексте исполнения

Comment: Если он у вас еще не загружен, то все верно. Укажите у функции class_exists() вторым параметром `true`.

Comment: @Visman Так для этого параметра true - значение по-умолчанию. Зачем его указывать?

Comment: class_exists по-умолчанию вызывает механизм автозагрузки

Comment: @tutankhamun, значит я невнимательно читал мануалы :)

Comment: @Visman А кто же их внимательно читает? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use Controller\HomeController имеется

Директива `use` - синтаксических сахар времени компиляции. Когда выполняется `class_exists` этой директивы уже нет и потому имя класса необходимо указывать полностью.

```
echo $controller; //HomeController
$fullControllerName = '\\Controller\\' . $controller;
if (class_exists($fullControllerName)){
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все теперь стало понятно.